# Will this array method keep updating the [0] index, or will it move the previous text back?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a method bringing in text every 600000 milliseconds, this is added to an array through the following method:

```
String[] namesArray = { };
Array.Resize(ref namesArray, namesArray.Length + 1);
namesArray[namesArray.Length - 1] = nameSplit;
```

I was curious, is this just replacing the array with the new text, or is it pushing the old index up to [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAgTy.png). Example if the text that came through was `Jim`, would this be placed in [0]. When the next comes through and it is "Harry", will "Jim" be pushed to [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAgTy.png) and "Harry" to [0]. Let me know if more code is required.

EDIT
[image]

Comment: Let us  know why you don't try it.. (Hint: you could speed up the process, if you are really interested!)

Comment: I can't I have a huge series of code. I just need someone who understands the algorithm to be able to help me. I can't tell if it is just replacing the [0] index

Comment: I assume `String[] namesArray = { };` is only executed on initialization, not with the other two lines? If not, you'll only ever end up with a single-element array.

Comment: That is wear I first created the array, just under the initialization component. It has not been filled before I am adding.

Comment: The [Array.Resize documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx) shows that when the array is resized, the current elements remain where they were before the resize.

Comment: Will the names be unique? If they are, you could use a `Dictionary<string,int>` mapping the names to the amounts, rather than two lists.

Comment: [Pieter Witvoet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26962947/1149773) has given a good answer below. Feel free to switch to that as the accepted answer if it meets your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what your code is doing:

```
String[] namesArray = { };                         // Create a new zero-element array.
Array.Resize(ref namesArray, namesArray.Length + 1);   // Increase size of array by 1.
namesArray[namesArray.Length - 1] = nameSplit;      // Assign to array's last element.
```

Thus, the end-result is that you would have a one-element array whose content is your `nameSplit` variable. This is equivalent to:

```
String[] namesArray = { nameSplit };
```

Subsequent calls will results in a new one-element array being created and assigned to `namesArray`.

Comment: Hmm, thanks! How could I have it so that a new element is created each time that `nameSplit` is changed? `nameSplit` being the data from the textfile.

Comment: Arrays are the wrong tool for the job. Create a `List<string>` at the beginning, then call `list.Add(nameSplit)` for each element you want to add to it.

Comment: Let me give that a try, thanks for the suggestion. I'll contact you again if I find any issues. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, please view the edit... I am unsure of how to grab the index for each list. Basically, if the name was added previously then it searches and grabs its index.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually resizing an array, consider using a `List<T>` instead. It's basically a self-resizing array. Instead of using two arrays, one for the names and another for the amounts, it's better to make a struct or class that groups a name and amount together, so you can use a single list:

```
public struct NameAndAmount
{
    public string Name;
    public int Amount;

    public NameAndAmount(string name, int amount)
    {
        Name = name;
        Amount = amount;
    }
}

List<NameAndAmount> items = new List<NameAndAmount>();
items.Add(new NameAndAmount("test", 100));
```

However, if you need to perform lookups by name, you may want to use a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead, using the names as keys and the amounts as values:

```
Dictionary<string, int> items = new Dictionary<string, int>();

// Check if a name has been stored before:
if (items.ContainsKey(name))
    int previousAmount = items[name];

// Store a name and amount:
items[name] = amount;
```

Comment: +1 Good answer. One suggestion: Use `items.TryGetValue` to check-and-retrieve with just one lookup (instead of two).